# How can I save url and local images?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm working on a project that uses the Spotify API. I get all the top tracks and top artists from users. I save the information into my database, the image that I get from Spotify is a URL image. Like this https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27300d5163a674cf57fe79866a6

In my CMS I want to be able to change the image of an artist or track. For this, I copied the code from the docs https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#image-1 "public function setImageAttribute($value) and put this in my model. Everything is working fine for this part, I can upload a new image and it saves into my public folder and gets displayed in my table.

The problem that I have is that when a new user logs in and the artist/track data needs to be saved in the database it goes through this setImageAttribute($value) in the model and doesn't add the URL into the database column.

Is there a way that I can add the URL image without going through the setImageAttribute function in the model?

The controller:

```
//get Top Artists
            $client = new Client([]);
            $topartists = $client->get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists?time_range=medium_term&limit=25&offset=5', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                ],
            ]);
            $listtopartists = json_decode($topartists->getBody(), true);
    
            $p = 25;
        foreach ($listtopartists['items'] as $topartist) {
            $artist = TopArtist::where('artist_id', $topartist['id'])->first();
            $artist_genre = json_encode($topartist['genres']);

            if ($artist === null) {
                $new_artist = TopArtist::create([
                    'artist_id' => $topartist['id'],
                    'name' => $topartist['name'],
                    'genres' => $artist_genre,
                    'users_popularity' => $p,
                    'popularity' => $topartist['popularity'],
                    'image' => $topartist['images'][0]['url'],
                    'url' => $topartist['external_urls']['spotify'],
                ]);

                $spotify_user->topArtists()->attach($new_artist->id);

            } else {

                $exists = $spotify_user->topArtists()->where('spotify_user_id', $spotify_user->id)->where('top_artist_id', $artist->id)->get();

                if ($exists->isEmpty()) {
                    $spotify_user->topArtists()->attach($artist->id);
                }
            }
            $p--;
        }
```

The Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class TopArtist extends Model
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'artist_id',
        'name',
        'popularity',
        'users_popularity',
        'url',
        'image',
        'genres',
        'status',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'status' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function setImageAttribute($value)
    {
        $attribute_name = "image";
        // or use your own disk, defined in config/filesystems.php
        $disk = config('backpack.base.root_disk_name');
        // destination path relative to the disk above
        $destination_path = "public/storage/artists";
        // if the image was erased
        if ($value==null) {
            // delete the image from disk
            \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});
            // set null in the database column
            $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
        }

        // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
        if (Str::startsWith($value, 'data:image'))
        {
            $image = \Image::make($value)->encode('jpg', 90);
            $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
            \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image->stream());
            \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});
            $public_destination_path = Str::replaceFirst('public/', '', $destination_path);
            $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $public_destination_path.'/'.$filename;
        }
    }

    public function spotifyUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\SpotifyUser::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, I had to add an else statement after

```
if (Str::startsWith($value, 'data:image'))
```

in the model where I set `$this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $value;`.

Comment: That's a good way to do it in my opinion. Heads-up, in the next version of Backpack (4.2, due in Dec 2021), you'll be able to move the image uploading logic to the field, to keep you mutator clean. When it's out, pay special attention to the "Eloquent Model events inside fields" section - basically the functionality provided in PR https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/4009